# Editable.setSpan() on Gingerbread: start and end parameters ignored

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to highlight two parts of the text in `EditText`. Here's how I do it:

```
EditText etOpenAnswer;
int correctPartEndIndex;
UnderlineSpan correctPartSpan=new UnderlineSpan();
StrikethroughSpan incorrectPartSpan=new StrikethroughSpan();

if (etOpenAnswer.length()>=correctPartEndIndex) {
    etOpenAnswer.getText().setSpan(correctPartSpan, 0, correctPartEndIndex, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    etOpenAnswer.getText().setSpan(incorrectPartSpan, correctPartEndIndex, etOpenAnswer.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
}
```

So first part of the text is from `0` to `correctPartEndIndex` (it is underlined), second is from `correctPartEndIndex` to the end (it is striked through). 
Everything works as expected on ICS and later, but on 2.2 and 2.3.3 both spans are applied to the whole text (text is underlined and striked through at the same time), which makes me think `start` and `end` parameters are just ignored.

What am I doing wrong?